# Why he is so sad

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, poetry, video-games

> My memories are only slices
>
> As my brain and nerves just blasted.
>
> My hands and feet are so cold
>
> So I'd rather wish them burnt.
>
> My vehicle just ran out of gas
>
> Yet it has 100% of the battery.
>
> My ego can't endure this moment
>
> Because I just lost all my ____.

What is the missing word? It has 4 letters.

My first attempt of an English poem, enjoy!

Subtle hint:

> They may not rhyme, but...

Moderate hint:

> The "video games" tag justifies why there must be 8 lines.

Decisive hint:

> My blood is full of iron
>
>  Along with nitrogen bubbles.
>
>  This situation is so hot
>
>  That I would kick down trees.
>
>  I can't even gasp my breath
>
>  Yet I could do destructions.
>
>  The phrase "let there be light"
>
>  Is lingering around me so fast.

Comment: This could easily refer to damage types or possibly attack/spell options in some video game, but I'm not seeing obvious clues to what game.

Comment: @aschepler Should consider the moderate hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your reply to @cinico, we know that

> Mega Man is involved.

So, I think you're all out of

> **guts**

because

> there are eight lines (as pointed out by one of the hints), and there are also eight bosses in the original Mega Man game.
>
>   @Braegh has also pointed out that a couple of replacement "Robot Masters" from a remake of the game fit a couple of the clues better, so they are included below.

---

My memories are only slices

> *slices* => **Cut Man**

As my brain and nerves just blasted.

> *blasted* => **Bomb Man**

My hands and feet are so cold

> *cold* => **Ice Man**

So I'd rather wish them burnt.

> *burnt* => **Fire Man**

My vehicle just ran out of gas

> *gas* => **Yellow Devil** (I think this is because, in combat, Yellow Devil may break into pieces and float to the other side of the battlefield)
>
>  Alternatively: *gas* => **Oil Man** from the game's remake, Mega Man Powered Up

Yet it has 100% of the battery.

> *battery* => **Elec Man**

My ego can't endure this moment

> *ego* => **Copy Robot** (steals Mega Man's identity)
>
>   Alternatively: *moment* => **Time Man** from the game's remake, Mega Man Powered Up

Because I just lost all my ____.

> *guts* => **Guts Man** (Having no guts figuratively means having no courage, which makes it difficult to continue. If taken literally, having lost your guts would certainly hinder your endurance even further...also, ewww)

Comment: ...and the decisive hint is the same thing from #2.

Comment: @BenBarden The hint! I forgot to reference that. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: There's also a remake, apparently, which adds a "Oil Man" and a "Time Man" - which can fit "gas" and "moment", respectively

Comment: @Braegh Thanks, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: What are the chances!? I got the game right right but everything that led me there was wrong. ahah!

Comment: rot13(Abgr gung gurve jrncbaf naq jrnxarffrf sbez n plpyr, naq gur yvarf ner nppbeqvatyl.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Bits

Because

> The character lost all his/her contents. Since it's a video game character, all the contents was stored in the memory (of a computer or so).

Also

> There are 8 bits in a byte

Comment: And let's not forget the music!

Comment: Gah! Sorry, but that's not the correct answer. rot13(Gur "ivqrb tnzr" gnt ersref gb n fcrpvsvp tnzr.)

Answer (score 1):

I still couldn't relate to all the clues, but I think the answer is

> Mega

Because

> "My ego" VS. "M Ega" is a word play, that doesn't rhyme, but... It's similar enough. The first part of the riddle seems to describe Mega Man, the video game hero that can shoot fire from his hands and feet. In the plot of the video game, Dr Light (hence the hint "let there be light") created a robot that started destroying and attacking everything. Mega man was originally a 8 bit game.

Comment: Extremely close!

Comment: rot13(Lbh cvpxrq gur evtug tnzr. Abj eryngr gur pyhrf pbeerpgyl.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a weak shot. Is the 4-letter word

> Time?

Explanation

> “Slices” are similar to “blasted” in the sense that both means the object referred is in pieces.
>  “Cold” and “burnt” are similar in the way that both are damage done due to extreme temperature.
>  “Gas” and “battery” are similar in the fact that they are both fuels.
>  So a 4-letter word similar to “moment” would be “time”.

Comment: On the second thought, I think you should consider the "video-games" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Sad because he lost his

> Life?

Explanation:

> I think everything is explained with someone who is leaving this world:
>  Memories are only something physical, sliced ​​in the brain.
>  As my brain and my nerves simply exploded agrees with leaving life.
>  My hands and feet are so cold because I am dying.
>  I'd rather burn them because it cold and mean I'm dying.
>  My vehicle ran out of gas is a comparison with reaching the end of life.
>  However, it has 100% battery. It could mean I'm leaving early...
>  My ego can't last this moment means the worst moment you can go through.
>  Because I just lost all my **life**.

Comment: Consider the "video games" tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe

> coin

because

> you can`t continue if you ran out of money. Super Mario is collecting gold coins.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your reply to @cinico I'm going to guess

> tank

Because

> Mega man (Rock man)'s life system is based on energy tanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is

Because I just lost all my

> Guts

**Explanation:**

My memories are only slices

> Cut man

As my brain and nerves just blasted.

> Bomb man

My hands and feet are so cold

> Ice Man

So I'd rather wish them burnt.

> Fire Man

My vehicle just ran out of gas

> Wily Machine (a vehicle)

Yet it has 100% of the battery.

> Elec Man

My ego can't endure this moment

> Copy Robot (ego -> self -> clone/copy)

Each of these is

> A boss in the original Megaman

so the last line refers to

> Guts Man

And he is sad because he is

> Blue

Comment: Gah! Inaccurate explanation.

Comment: Look at @CGreen's answer, I'm sure they have it